# Custom Linux Desktop Environment on Electron

Tags: linux, user-interface, electron

Is it possible to create Desktop Environment like KDE or GNOME using Electron framework?
How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Electron is a Node.js Server with Chromium as a Frontend. So you can build cross platform applications using all the power of Node. That's nice but not even near the tasks and settings a desktop enviroment like GNOME or KDE have to manage.

I see absolutely no way achieving what you are looking for.